# Django OneToMany form on related model

Tags: django, forms, one-to-many

I've created a onetomany relationship between two models. The model
that has the foreignkey I can use their formset without problems, but
now I want to fill this relation through the form of the model that
has the "many", I know I can retrieve it using the *_set, but how
can I create a MultipleChoiceField form element of this data?

Thanks for any help!

Regards,

Thiago

Comment: [TTIWWC](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (This Thread Is Worthless Without Code)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs for [fields which handle relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships). You could use a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) -- it's essentially a `MultipleChoiceField` that takes its choices from a queryset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how I bound this ModelMultipleChoiceField to the relation? I bound it to *_set? My doubt is how Django knows how to update the related models.